# Access @JobScope bean in spring batch with partitioned step

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Is there a way to access bean which is defined as `@JobScope` in partitioned step?

We defined http client bean as `@JobScope` since it is unique per job but dynamically created and we need it in slave steps to issue post requests. When we autowire everything we get

```
Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.captureErpStockTasklet':
Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a 
scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton;
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder 
available for step scope
```

Here is job configuration class (I have removed everything not needed, left only configuration of partitioned step and `Client` class which is in `@JobScope` because on every job run it needs to be job specific:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.importjob"})
public class FrozenFileImportJobConfig {
@Value("${thread.pool:10}")
private int threadPoolSize;
@Value("${partitioner.max.thread.pool:10}")
private int maxThreadPoolSize;
@Value("${grid.size:10}")
private int gridSize;
@Value("${client.url:some_url}")
private int url;
@Value("${client.id:client_id}")
private int clientId;
@Value("${client.secret:secret}")
private int clientSecret;
@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
 @Autowired
private ErpStockIdPartitioner erpStockIdPartitioner;
@Autowired
private CaptureErpStockTasklet captureErpStockTasklet;
@Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
@JobScope
public Client client() {
  return new Client(url, clientId, clientSecret);
}

public ExecutionContextPromotionListener contextPromotionListener() {
  final ExecutionContextPromotionListener executionContextPromotionListener = new ExecutionContextPromotionListener();
  executionContextPromotionListener.setKeys(new String[] {"erp_stock_ids"});
  return executionContextPromotionListener;
}

public Step captureErpStockDBTaskletStep() {
  return stepBuilderFactory.get("captureErpStockDBTaskletStep").tasklet(captureErpStockTasklet).build();
}

@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor erpStockIdTaskExecutor() {
  final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
  threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(threadPoolSize);
  threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(maxThreadPoolSize);
  threadPoolTaskExecutor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
  return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
}
public Step partitioningCaptureStep() {
  return stepBuilderFactory.get("partitioningCaptureStep").partitioner(captureErpStockDBTaskletStep())
.partitioner("erpStockIdPartitioner", erpStockIdPartitioner).taskExecutor(erpStockIdTaskExecutor())
.gridSize(gridSize).allowStartIfComplete(true).build();
}
@Bean
public Job riverIslandFrozenFileImportJob() {
  return jobBuilderFactory.get("riverIslandFrozenFileImportJob").start(partitioningCaptureStep()).build();
}
}
```

And here is `captureErpStockDBTasklet` which is invoked as partitioned step from master `partitioningCaptureStep`:

```
@Component
@StepScope
public class CaptureErpStockTasklet implements Tasklet {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CaptureErpStockTasklet.class);
  @Value("#{jobParameters[" + FtpJobParameters.ORGANIZATION_ID + "]}")
  private Long organizationId;
  @Autowired
  private ErpStockRepository erpStockRepository;
  @Autowired
  private Client client;
  @Override
  public RepeatStatus execute(final StepContribution contribution, final ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    //importing of erp stock from DB, nothing special in that code so removed
     client.captureErpStock(stock);
     LOG.info("[{}] Finished importing ERP {}", organizationId, erpStock);
     return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
  }
}
```

When I change in configuration `Clinet` to be `@StepScope` it works fine but than I get client created for every step which is not what I want, I want to have one for entire job.

Comment: Can you add the job definition (xml/javaconfig) and the class that uses CaptureErpStockTasklet

Comment: I added java configuration class and tasklet. As in post when I change client to be `@StepScope` it works fine but that is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is an issue in spring batch when useing Job Scope beans in a partitioned step.

See: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2269
And 
[Multi-threaded acces to Job Scope beans in Spring Batch 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558703/multi-threaded-acces-to-job-scope-beans-in-spring-batch-3-0)

Comment: Thanks for links, guess I will follow jira ticket and do what was suggested